# representing a recursive difference equation of two variables into one variable equation

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, recurrence-relations

suppose the following recursive difference equation ($t$ is time):

$$x_t = \frac{a}{1+a}x_{t-1} + \frac{1}{1+a}x_{t+1}$$

where $0<a<1$ is assumed and all values of $a$ at past times are equally defined (by this, I mean: $x_{t-1} = \frac{a}{1+a}x_{t-2} + \frac{1}{1+a}x_{t}$) and there is no beginning time or ending time - time ranges from $-\infty$ to $\infty$.

I want to represent $x_t$ using purely $x_{t+1}$. What would the equation for $x_t$ be?

Edit:

I want to interpret the above equation as $x_t$ depending on $x_{t+1}$ and $x_{t-1}$, not the other way around.

Edit 2:

Let me rephrase my question. I now get a sort-of feeling that 
the above equation has to be $x_t = x_{t+1}$. Problem is, I can't prove it rigorously. Can anyone show what the rigorous proof would be?

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking. Are you referring to finding $R(t)$ such that $a_{t+1} = R(t) a_t$?

Comment: Yes, almost except that I am trying to find $x_t = R(t)x_{t+1}$.

Comment: OH. there was a typo. $a_t$ should have been $x_t$.

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking is equivalent to finding an expression for the 2nd order recursive relation
$$
x_{k}=(1+a)x_{k-1}-ax_{k-2}, \quad k\in \mathbb Z,
$$
This does have a general expression, and it is
$$
x_k=c_1\omega_1^k+c_2\omega_2^k,
$$
where $c_1,c_2$ constants and $\omega_1,\,\omega_2$ are the solutions of the quadratic equation
$$
X^2-(1+a)X+a=0,
$$
and these are $1$ and $a$. Hence
$$
x_k=c_1+c_2 a^k, \quad \text{for all}\,\, k\in\mathbb Z.
$$

Answer (score 0):

I assume what you actually mean is find $x_t$ as a function of $t$. Here are three hints for you:
$$
\text{Hint 1}:s= 1 \cdot s=\bigg(\frac{a}{1+a}+\frac{1}{1+a}\bigg)s\\
\text{Hint 2}:x_{t+1}-x_{t}=X_{t+1}\\
\text{Hint 3}:\sum_{k=1}^{t}X_{k}=x_{t}-x_{0}
$$